# How can I get item response id"s?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I have made a formsystem (Drivea) that can be used by bridgeclubs for signing up for a bridgedrive. The first question of the signing up form (form 1) is to choose between (1) signup, (2) change their former signedup data or (3) to withdraw from the bridgedrive after signing up earlier.
When people want to change their former signedup data they have to give only a numbercode (was given in the confirmationmail after signing up) and their emailadress. Directly they get an email in which the prefilled Url is given. This prefilled Url gives another form than the first form (with the 3 choises as mentioned above) with almost the same questions. The data are picked up from the responsesheet of the first form and filed in the prefilled Url from the second form. After changing data and submit the second form the new data are copied again to the responsesheet of form 1.
In the prefilled url are the itemresponse id's with corresponding data. These numbers are given by get the url of form 2. Those numbers are used in the script of form 1 to construct the prefilled Url. This is working very good because those numbers never change as long the questions of both forms are not changing.
So far so good.

Now I am developping that in the form a bridgeclub can add an extra question (item). They are able to remove that extra item and if necessarry to bring back an extra (other) question. This is possible by a few functions I made.
However when an extra item is set in the form (and automaticly also in form 2) every time the itemresonse Id is changing of that extra question. **So i am looking for a solution to find the response id of that question in form 2 before this question in the form was filled in.**

In a form you kan get the Id (number) of an item by item.getId(). When the form is made those Id's are allocated directly.
To get the itemresponse id's you have to go to the form (edit) en get the prefilled Url. After filling in and submit the form the url with the itemresponse id's is shown. As mentioned above for form 2.
It seems to me logical that, as with the item id's, those itemresponse id's are already known before filling in all answers of the form to get the prefilled Url.

My question is how can I get programmaticly those itemresponse id's?

Comment: Honestly I probably know less about what your doing than you do but checkout this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item)

Comment: Sorry that are no solutions...

Comment: There is a lot of information in your question that may not be needed for someone to understand what you want.  There are two Forms involved.  You want to get the question ID in Form2 BEFORE the corresponding question in Form1 is answered?  Maybe you can store the question ID in the document properties, when that question is added, and then look up the saved information that was stored.  My impression is, that you need some way of correlating matching questions in two Forms?  You'd need to save that information somewhere when the questions are made.  Unless the titles were the same, and then

Comment: you could search all the questions by Title, and look for a match.  But I'm not exactly sure what you really want.

Comment: Sorry I thought that background information is needed to understand my question. Perhaps a shorter question is how to get an itenResponse ID before filling in the answer of a formquestion (item)...?

Comment: Combining Cooper and Sandy suggestions, you can use the [ItemResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item) to get the responses. Now since the title or the question is the common variable we will use it as the marker to set the prefilled answer (as provided by @Sandy). IF extra question.title(Form1) and question.title(Form2) matched set prefilled answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Response Id numbers are not necessary to get the prefilled url.

```
OnformSubmit (e) {
......
var formResponse = form2.createResponse();
// Prefill first name
var formItem = itemsform2[0].asTextItem();
var response = formItem.createResponse(sourcedata[i-1][2]);
formResponse.withItemResponse(response);  
// Prefill insertion
var formItem = itemsform2[1].asTextItem();
var response = formItem.createResponse(sourcedata[i-1][3]);
formResponse.withItemResponse(response);
// Prefill family name
var formItem = itemsform2[2].asTextItem();
var response = formItem.createResponse(sourcedata[i-1][4]);
var url = formResponse.toPrefilledUrl();
......
}
```

i is the row in the response sheet of form 1, sourcedata is the answer in that row and formitem is the corresponding item in form 2.
It works very good.